# create new object column values if separate hourly datetime column lies between specified hourly range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column 'Flight_Time' that shows the hour and minute of a flight (%H:%M format e.g. 02:22, timedelta64[ns]) and I want to create a new column ( df['val'] ) that classifies the flight time as either '0-2hrs', '2-4hrs', '4-6hrs' or '6+hrs' so I can plot the total sum of each of these 4 new variables.

Can someone advise how i can set up the if statements below to create the 'val' column that can classify the 4 subsets? the flight time column is a timedelta64[ns] object.

```
if df['Flight_Time'] >= '0:00' & df['Flight_Time'] < '02:00':
    df['val'] = '0-2 hrs'
elif df['Flight_Time'] >= '2:00' & df['Flight_Time'] < '04:00':
    df['val'] = '2-4 hrs'
elif df['Flight_Time'] >= '4:00' & df['Flight_Time'] < '06:00':
    df['val'] = '4-6 hrs'
else:
    df['val'] = '6+ hrs'
```

Target dataframe output would be something like:

```
Flight Time  val
0   00:00   0-2 hr
1   00:01   0-2 hr
2   04:05   2-4 hr
3   10:08   6+ hr
4   02:10   2-4 hr
```

UPDATE:
I have changed my code to the below however now I am only getting 6+ hours in the newly created 'Val' column

```
from datetime import timedelta

for x in df["Flight_Time"]:
    if  timedelta(hours = 0, minutes = 0) < x <= timedelta(hours = 2, minutes = 0):
        df['val'] = '0-2 hrs'
    elif timedelta(hours = 2, minutes = 0) < x <= timedelta(hours = 4, minutes = 0):
        df['val'] = '2-4 hrs'
    elif timedelta(hours = 4, minutes = 0) < x <= timedelta(hours = 6, minutes = 0):
        df['val'] = '4-6 hrs'
    else:
        df['val'] = '6+ hrs'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"""it's a bit redundant as implementation
however it shows how to handle
rows and columns with pandas the way you want
- just add the comparison using datetime types
(because here I used integers)
"""

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0.5],
    [3],
    [5],
    [10]
], columns=["flight_time"])


df["flight_interval"] = None
df.loc[df["flight_time"] < 2, ["flight_interval"]] = "0-2 hrs"
df.loc[(df["flight_time"] > 2) & (df["flight_time"] < 4), ["flight_interval"]] = "2-4 hrs"
df.loc[(df["flight_time"] > 4) & (df["flight_time"] < 6), ["flight_interval"]] = "4-6 hrs"
df.loc[(df["flight_time"] > 6) , ["flight_interval"]] = "6+ hrs"
print(df)
```

Output

```
+----+---------------+-------------------+
|    |   flight_time | flight_interval   |
|----+---------------+-------------------|
|  0 |           0.5 | 0-2 hrs           |
|  1 |           3   | 2-4 hrs           |
|  2 |           5   | 4-6 hrs           |
|  3 |          10   | 6+ hrs            |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
```

-- EDIT: version with timedelta type

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0.5],
    [3],
    [5],
    [10]
], columns=["flight_time"])
df["flight_time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["flight_time"], unit="hours")

df["flight_interval"] = None
df.loc[df["flight_time"] < timedelta(hours=2), ["flight_interval"]] = "0-2 hrs"
df.loc[(df["flight_time"] > timedelta(hours=2)) & (df["flight_time"] < timedelta(hours=4)), ["flight_interval"]] = "2-4 hrs"
df.loc[(df["flight_time"] > timedelta(hours=4)) & (df["flight_time"] < timedelta(hours=6)), ["flight_interval"]] = "4-6 hrs"
df.loc[(df["flight_time"] > timedelta(hours=6)), ["flight_interval"]] = "6+ hrs"
```

```
+----+-----------------+-------------------+
|    | flight_time     | flight_interval   |
|----+-----------------+-------------------|
|  0 | 0 days 00:30:00 | 0-2 hrs           |
|  1 | 0 days 03:00:00 | 2-4 hrs           |
|  2 | 0 days 05:00:00 | 4-6 hrs           |
|  3 | 0 days 10:00:00 | 6+ hrs            |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hi pguardati thanks for your feedback however I have had still some minor issues. I modified my code to the above edits but still having a small error

Comment: Great you did, otherwise you can find the adapted version with date time in the edit!

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
df["val"] = pd.cut(df["Flight_Time"], bins=[2,4,6,8,10,12])
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I get the following ValueError: bins must be of timedelta64 dtype